# In emacs 23, how to replace word-left and word-right functions

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using libraries like simple-call-tree+.el which uses the functions (left-word)  and (right-word).
Unfortunately, seems my emacs 23 can't parse them and always gives me:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: left-word
```

How is it possible to coop with such situation?
Is there a library that I could include for these functions to be compatible?
Should I substitute them in the original function with something else?

Comment: For a test start emacs with `emacs -q` load `simple-call-tree+.el` and try again.

Comment: Tobias, I switched temporarily to emacs 24 to make sure all my stuff in .emacs still works.
One thing is missing me up is (disabling sync-window-mode).
After enabling it on blame, I wanted a quick function to return things to normal, but it did not, the slave buffer still follows the master:
(defun toggle-scroll-bar-kill ()
  (interactive)
  (sync-window-mode nil)
  (kill-other-buffer)
  (balance-windows)
  )
My question is how to disable sync-window-mode from inside .emacs file.

Comment: Try again with `M-: (sync-window-mode -1)`. In both windows. Maybe you were in the wrong one. `sync-window-mode` is just defined via `define-minor-mode`. This is why it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those functions decouple cursor movement from text flow direction.  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#Release_history), Emacs got bidirectional input support in version 24, so maybe they weren't in Emacs 23.  Anyway, if you're dealing with left to right text (e.g. English), `left-word` is the same as `backward-word` and `right-word` is the same as `forward-word`.  Source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/bindings.el#n767

BTW, get a newer version if you can.